# Grab focus to embedded window inside Gtk::Socket

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, xembed

I have embedded gvim inside a Gtk::Socket which is placed in a Gtk::Box, how can I grab focus to the embedded gvim window so that I achieve the same as actually pointing and clicking in the embedded window?

Using `->grab_focus()` on the Gtk::Socket widget does not have any effect.

According to the XEMBED spec (http://standards.freedesktop.org/xembed-spec/xembed-spec-latest.html#idm139742761059984) it seems that the embedder (Gtk::Socket) should send either a `XEMBED_FOCUS_IN` or a `XEMBED_WINDOW_ACTIVATE` signal to the child, but there does not seem to be an interface for this in Gtk::Socket.

An simple example of what I am trying to do based on the [Gtk::Plug and Gtk::Socket example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-plugs-sockets-example.html.en) can be found here: https://github.com/gauteh/plug-socket-grab-focus .

In case this is a bug, it has been reported here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=729248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are now two ways to achieve this, one is by using the patch as provided in: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=729248 which adds an `gtk_socket_focus_forward ()` method to `GtkSocket`. Calling this will focus the first widget inside the `Gtk::Plug` window.

An example of using `gtk_socket_focus_forward` can be found in the [focus_forward branch](https://github.com/gauteh/plug-socket-grab-focus/blob/focus_forward/sock.cc#L36) of an example adapted from the [standard example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-plugs-sockets-example.html.en).

The *second* way to achieve this is to send the `Gtk::DIR_TAB_FORWARD` signal as described on [the mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2014-August/msg00047.html), a similar example can be found in the [tab_forward](https://github.com/gauteh/plug-socket-grab-focus/blob/tab_forward/sock.cc#L39) branch.

This involves the following:

```
socket->set_can_focus (true);
socket->child_focus (Gtk::DIR_TAB_FORWARD);
```

The method does diverge slightly from what is possible with `gtk_socket_focus_forward`, but appears to do the trick.